# Notepad++ Regex help required

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a several hundred thousand line XML file that is full of data I don't need. I'm looking for a way to bulk delete thousands of irrelevant lines and am aware this can be done through find-and-replace with a regex. But my regex skills are basically non-existent.

The file is XML compliant so every line starts and ends with tags. An example block that recurs hundreds of times throughout the document is:

`<g:payment_accepted>Visa</g:payment_accepted>
<g:payment_accepted>Cash</g:payment_accepted>
<g:payment_accepted>MasterCard</g:payment_accepted>
<g:payment_accepted>Check</g:payment_accepted>
<g:payment_accepted>WireTransfer</g:payment_accepted>`

So in this instance I want a regex to search for instances:

```
<g:payment_accepted>WILDCARD_ANYTHING_IN_BETWEEN</g:payment_accepted>
```

Once I have a working regex I understand, I can tweak it for other repeated tag blocks in the document. No idea where to start though.

Comment: Ah I've just gone and worked it out, easier than I thought it would be, this does the trick

^(<g:payment_accepted>).*(</g:payment_accepted>)$

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Feel free to post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just put `.*` wherever you want to allow anything. the caret at the beginning marks the start of a line and the dollar sign at the end represents the end of a line.

`^<g:payment_accepted>.*</g:payment_accepted> $`

(Putting the OP’s comment into an answer to make the solution easier to find.)

Comment: This is a copy of OP's comment. At least give them a credit or best, make this answer a community wiki.

Comment: @Toto thanks I did that. I wanted the answer to be easier to find.